# How to add components programatically in vuejs (option api)

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I am creating a map app using vue-leaflet and I'm trying to add paths when clicked on map.
I have everything set up but don't know how to add that `l-polyline` option in my template during runtime.
I tried to add it with DOM Api but it is taking it as it is without converting it to html

I want to add my component inside `<l-map></l-map>`

this is my map initialization

```
<l-map
  class="mainMap"
  ref="map"
  v-if="isLocAvailable"
  v-model="zoom"
  v-model:zoom="zoom"
  :center="currLocation"
  @zoom="zoomUpperBound"
  :options="{ zoomControl: false, maxZoom: 18 }"
  @click="getCurrLoc"
>
```

and this is my getCurrLoc:

```
getCurrLoc(e) {
  try {
    const { lat, lng } = e.latlng;
    if (this.onCreateMode === true) {
      this.locations.push([lat, lng]);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("what is err");
  }
},
```

and i also have function for creating polyline in which i want to add that path adding functionality

```
createPolyline() {
  console.log(this.locations);
  //Code

  //Reset Inputs
  this.pathName = "";
  this.onCreateMode = false;
  this.locations = [];
},
```

Comment: It's unclear where exactly a component needs to be added and whether there should be only one. All the ways are known - dynamic <component>, v-if, v-for, probably combined

Comment: the paths will be multiple and inside ```l-map```

Comment: Use v-for with some array, probably `locations`